# Detecting moving headlines in news channels (news tickers)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, video-processing

Is it possible to detect (and extract) the moving headlines from a news video using tools like FFMpeg, Leptonica and Tesseract OCR.
For an input video, what can be done to extract continuous ticker text using the overlapping text from two frames?
Ref: [News ticker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker)